# Radar chart using Chart.js not working

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, chart.js

I am trying to follow the chart example listed in [salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm) doc and a [blog](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/create-radar-chart-lightning-component/), i am getting an error on the JS load functionality as below and the charts are not getting loaded and i get the error screen that Radar.function(xxxX) is not valid.

I have used a static resource with name chart_js and included in the component. Is there anything missing?

below is my code :

Component:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.chart_js}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}"/>

    <div class="heading">
        Radar Chart showing Lead count by Source
    </div>

    <div>  
        <canvas aura:id="radarChart" id="radarCHart123" width="400" height="400"/>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Error 
[image]

JS controller

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) { 
        helper.setupRadarChart(component);
    }
})
```

Helper

```
 ({
        setupRadarChart : function(component) {

        var action = component.get("c.getLeadJSON");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
            var jsonRetVal = JSON.parse(a.getReturnValue()); 
            console.log(jsonRetVal.radarLabels);

            var radarChartData = {
            labels: jsonRetVal.radarLabels,
            datasets: [
                { 
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: jsonRetVal.radarData
                }
            ]
        };

        var el = component.find('radarChart').getElement();
        var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
        new Chart(ctx).Radar(radarChartData);   

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },  

})
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124690

Comment: Also, can we see your JavaScript controller code that involves Radar? It may be related.

Comment: @Anil Without seeing your JS code ,nobody will be able to help you .Please post the JS code you are using .

Comment: thanks guys, just added my JS code too, honestly i am still playing around with the charts and the code is straight from the blog post.

Comment: @Anil Are you using same controller class as that blog suggests ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava yes mohit, i am using exactly the same code in the blog, no changes made yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple of problems here causing the issue

1.The server is returning JSON and you are using JSON.parse to manually deserialise the JSON .The app is breaking due to this .

2.The locker does not support the function "**gContext2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled**"

> gContext2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled' is deprecated and will be removed in M55, around November 2016. Please use 'CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled' instead.

So this means you will manually edit the file and where ever you used gContext2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled you will use "**CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled**"

I have tried by disabling locker and just not using the apex controller to narrow down the issue .

Here is the code thats completely working now

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="RadarChartData">
 <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Chartjs}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}"/>
<div class="heading">
    Radar Chart showing Lead count by Source
</div>

<div>  
    <canvas aura:id="radarChart" id="radarChart" width="400" height="400"/>
</div>
```

The JS controller

```
({
init : function(component, event, helper) { 
    console.log('Test');
    helper.setupRadarChart(component);
 }
```

})

The Helper code

```
({
setupRadarChart : function(component) {

var data = {
labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
        }
    ]
};
    var el = component.find('radarChart').getElement();
    var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
    console.log(ctx);
    new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "radar",
    data: data,
    options: {
            scale: {
                reverse: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
      }
   });

  } 
})
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

You can deactivate locker by using critical updates but strongly suggest not to and instead once you tested the code ,edit the Static resource chartJs library and modify to use CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled wherever applicable .

Comment: I second that - spectacular work on this Mohith! As a follow up have either of you opened an Issue or submitted a pull request to get this fixed in Chartjs https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js ? What version of Chartjs are you using?

Comment: @doug It's 2.4 latest release in the chart.js library .The file is in their git repo

Comment: Are you going to submit a pull request to Chartjs with the proposed fix to remove the use of a WebKit specific deprecated API?

Comment: Are you going to submit a pull request to Chartjs with the proposed fix to remove the use of a WebKit specific deprecated API?

Comment: @DougChasman Going to create an issue that there library should use this to be locker compliant and will take from there .Thanks !

Comment: @DougChasman Issue created https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3630

Comment: @DougChasman Looks like it is issue with locker .Please check the thread https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3630#issuecomment-262235867 .I can raise a case if you need further assistance .

Comment: We are running into Javascript errors with ChartJS on Safari only, anyone else facing the same?  @MohithShrivastava 

Attached screenshot gives idea about the error. 

https://uploads.disquscdn.com/images/9a5dba5c60dd63557f277b296b483f2597a9bb7f41442eacc0fe10c8cc273cde.png